# How does LSOF map port to process on Solaris?

Tags: process, mapping, port, solaris, lsof

I have an idea of how it's done on Linux, they probably go through /proc//fd and to display the sockets used by each process.

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like the /proc//fd entries list sockets on Solaris.  Does anyone know how lsof would do it on this system?  Or how one would even go about this in general?

Just to restate what exactly it is I need: I need some way to find which processes are listening to which ports (without using lsof of course) on Solaris.

Comment: Any reason why you gave up following this question and its answers and asked a very similar one elsewhere? Also why do you state "without using lsof of course" ?

Comment: All of the answers given here either don't do what I need, or are missing part.  The one answer tells me to use something on Solaris 11.2, which isn't the system I'm running.  Your answer only sorta gets halfway to where I'm trying to get.  I found another tool I could use and wanted to ask a question about it outside of the context of this thread.

I state "without using lsof of course" because the very nature of my question is finding an alternative to lsof...I don't know what you're trying to get at.

Comment: My question is about the why "of course"? i.e. what is wrong using lsof while it seems to achieve what you want? Also, as my answer is only going halfway to what you are trying to get, feel free to tell me what is missing as a comment.

Comment: lsof is unavailable on the system

Comment: Okay, so I understand you are not writing C code but want to get this information from a shell script. As you were looking for lsof internals, I thought you wanted to reuse its internal method in C.

Comment: I need something that can do this.  I can either find what mechanism lsof uses and try to duplicate it in my code, or pipe the shell script's output into my program and parse it.  The important part is finding SOME way to correlate port numbers with the process that has it open.

Comment: If writing/integrating source code is acceptable, why not reusing (parts of) lsof source? It is freely available and its license is quite permissive.

Answer (score 0):

`/proc/<pid>/fd` lists all open file descriptors, including those associated with a socket, eg:

```
# pwd
/proc/408/fd
# ls -l
total 4
c---------   1 root     sys       13,  2 Jul 31 23:12 0
c---------   1 root     sys       97,  1 Jul 31 23:06 1
p---------   0 root     root           0 Jul 31 23:06 10
p---------   0 root     root           0 Jul 31 23:06 11
c---------   1 root     sys       97,  1 Jul 31 23:06 2
-r--r--r--   1 root     root        1209 Jul 31 23:06 3
D---------   1 root     root           0 Jul 31 23:06 4
s---------   0 root     root           0 Jul 31 23:06 5
s---------   0 root     root           0 Jul 31 23:06 6
p---------   0 root     root           0 Jul 31 23:06 7
p---------   0 root     root           0 Jul 31 23:06 8
s---------   0 root     root           0 Jul 31 23:06 9
```

Here file descriptors `5`,`6` and `9` are definitely sockets, as shows their `s` file type.

Not sure about what `lsof` is doing under the cover but to get socket details, `pfiles` is reading the process internal structures. See its [dosocket](https://github.com/joyent/illumos-joyent/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/ptools/pfiles/pfiles.c#L761) methods.

Comment: So the s at the beginning of the line signifies that it's a socket?  I'm mainly looking for alternatives to pfiles because that ends up being very slow (I need to do this quickly).

Comment: Yes, `s` means socket as documented ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/816-0210/6m6nb7me6/index.html#ls-1-indx-1 ). You can filter out the processes having no socket open and only query the sockets file descriptors in custom code.

Comment: So, this returns the file descriptors, but how do I get what port those are corresponding to?  I looked into this a bit myself after getting your answer and I couldn't find anything about how to do that.

Comment: If you want to retrieve the ports using a shell script, the first options I see are the already mentioned pfiles or a script based on ndd/mdb. Are you looking to some particular tcp ports or all ports in use?

Comment: I'd be looking for all ports.  I don't want to use pfiles because it is extremely slow in comparison to everything else and there is possible instability since it pauses the processes to examine them.  I am looking into mdb and I seem to have found something I can do with it.

Comment: You can filter out all processes that have no socket open by looking their /proc/*/fd directories, then you can use pfiles method to get the port information. Pfiles is exploring all file descriptors, not just the network related ones so your implementation would be faster. Pfiles is suspending a process while it scans its file descriptor table. This table being dynamic, not suspending the process might give erroneous data or even crash the reading process.

Comment: According to pfiles man page http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9ng/index.html#Warnings it is possible to cause daemons to crash when it pauses them.  This is just an unacceptable side effect in this situation.

Comment: As far as I know, this is only known to happen with some very specific time sensitive clustering components. Being suspended for a short period of time is otherwise something all Unix processes are expected to experience without damage. I have routinely run `pfiles` on probably tens of thousands of Solaris productions servers without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running Solaris 11.2, you can use `netstat -u`.  Per the [man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36871/netstat-1m.html#REFMAN1Mnetstat-1m):

> -u
>
> Lists the user, process id, and the program which originally created the network endpoint or controls it now.

Comment: Unfortunately it is only Solaris 11.0